# When you return object by reference, when do you need to be worried that the object will be destroyed?

Tags: c++

you have the following:

```
Person& getPersonByName(string name);
```

In what circumstances do you need to be worried that the return person from the getPersonByName will be destructed as soon as the method ended so the caller method will work on destructed data?

Thank you

Comment: If you e.g. return a reference to a local non-static variable, then it will lead to trouble because local variables are always destructed when the function returns, leaving you with a reference to a non-existing object.

Comment: @user1495181,  I've edited your question a little.  Your original question implied that it is never a problem to return a reference.  I've corrected this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should.

This is `dangling reference` for example:

```
Person &getPerson()
{
    Person p;
    return p;
} //p is destroyed here
```

But this is ok:

```
Person &getPerson()
{
    static Person p;
    return p;
}
```

You can also return a `reference` to some internal variable of an `object` and it's ok to use it until the `object` is destroyed:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int & getA() {return a;}

private:
    int a;
};
```

Comment: Will the const prevent from the return to be destroyed until the caller ended ????

Comment: "If yo return const& it's guaranteed that life time of variable will be prolonged to lifetime of the reference". Really? Can you provide quote from standard?

Comment: @yurikilochek: here: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: "In that case, it's guaranteed that the life time of variable will be prolonged to lifetime of the reference": not in this case.  First, the lifetime of _variables_ used to initialize a reference is never changed; second, returning a reference is an exception even for temporaries (since extending the lifetime of the temporary beyond the end of the function isn't implementable); and third, even if it was, it generally wouldn't help you, because the lifetime of the returned reference is only that of the full expression which contained the call.

Comment: @JamesKanze: you are right, I've edited the answer. I think I should reread the article

Comment: @Andrew A definite improvement.  Although I'm not sure I agree that the version with a static variable is OK; it's going to lead to no end of problems if you ever go multithreaded.  (Using a const static variable and returning a const reference to it _is_ OK.  But having all sorts of clients arbitrarily modifying a static variable is a sure route to trouble.)

Comment: Andrew, If i am going to use in the return person for long period , do you recommend that in this case i will return by value  and not used the const with & ?

Comment: @user1495181: if using a copy is enough for you - I would go with copy since it's simpler. Otherwise consider using `shared_ptr`

Comment: Wots wrong with new() and returning a pointer?  It is me, or is that the obvious way of handling a factory method like this?

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't think the question was in case of multithreading. But of course you need synchronization in that case. Moreover, returning a const reference is not enough in that case because you will also have to protect the initialization of the variable

Comment: @Andrew You shouldn't need protection for the initialization of the variable.  On the other hand, if any of the clients modifies the variable (and if they don't, you should return a const reference), then all of the clients will need to synchronize their accesses to it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: you need. Since a static variable is created on the first call of the function and if two threads will call these function together one may start creation and the other may start using not fully created object

Comment: @JamesKanze ,@Andrew You lost me. I think that if i use signature with const i have a protection and the refernece is not dangling, but now i understand that this is a mistake and const reference doesn’t help me. is this the bottom line?

Comment: @Andrew It's the implementations problem to make it work.  According to C++11, anyway---earlier versions of C++ didn't support threading at all (but g++ has made it work for a long time now).

Comment: @user1495181 If you return a reference, it makes no difference whether the reference is const or not.  If you return a value, it can only be bound to a const reference (or copied); binding it to a const reference will extend the lifetime, so that the reference effectively behaves exactly as if you'd used a value (except for the extra noise in the source file).

Comment: @JamesKanze: it's not about implementation. Consider the case where a static variable constructor is long. One thread starts creating the object, than the context is switched to the other thread which starts working with object, but it is not constructed yet.

Comment: @Andrew The C++11 standard says it has to work.  It works in g++.  The implementation is required to do whatever synchronization is necessary.  An implementation which doesn't do the synchronization is broken, at least as far as C++11 is concerned (but also from a QoI point of view if it claims to support multithreading).

Answer (score 3):

If `Person` doesn't get destroyed when the function returns. Examples include

- Static storage duration variables
- Member variables of the class that returning function is a method of.

Comment: The case is like in Andrew answer.